laptop fan spinning faster since upgrade to 24.04
Since upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04, my Dell XPS 9530 laptop's fans spin almost constantly, even when doing very little (around 2-3% CPU usage).
I tried fixing it with powertop --auto-tune, which helped somewhat, but the fans definitely aren't as quiet as before the upgrade.
For example, with the CPU at 2% usage and the temperature at 55°C, the fan is still spinning at 3600 RPM.
Has anyone else encountered this same issue?
